# Should I accept this promotion or not?

Tags: promotion

I'm currently a Senior  Database Administrator at a popular financial firm. I'm very +tive I will be offered a Team Lead Promotion in 2021 Summer.
However neither leading a team nor managing people interests me , again I think I'm good at it like in communicating , bringing people together and tech stack wise I wear multiple hats. I may lend myself naturally into a TL but do not want to become one.
The reason I do not want to choose the managerial line is:

1. I think it reduces my movement across organizations ( Enterprises
   rarely hire for Team Leads or Managers)
2. Its a bad idea to seek the
   managerial path if I do not have plans to stick on to this
   organization for long term i.e another 5 years.
3. My long term goal is
   to be a well paid consultant and work remotely for limited hours (
   lots of flexibility) If I accept this promotion of TL I might not be
   able to dedicate enough time to master my craft which I think is
   necessary for my long term goal.
4. However hate to lose $ that comes
   with the promotion

   I'm planning to ask to keep my position as is but still give me that
   increment that comes with the promotion, however I think it would
   not happen.

Please advise and clarify if some of my assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always advise people to keep their long term goals in mind. If your long term goal is not to be in management, then don't accept a management position. And particularly if neither leading a team nor managing people interests you, then by all means don't be a manager. The world doesn't need uninterested managers.

As far as your assumption...

> I think it reduces my movement across organizations ( Enterprises
> rarely hire for Team Leads or Managers)

That may be true in your organizations. It's not true for the companies where I worked. In the latter part of my career, I was always hired in at a Manager level or higher. Nothing rare about it.

It's always true that there are fewer managers than there are individual contributors. But if you are a good at what you do, that's not a problem.

> Its a bad idea to seek the managerial path if I do not have plans to
> stick on to this organization for long term i.e another 5 years.

Five years is a long time. In software, most people don't stay with a company that long. I don't see why that would have any relevance to going into management.

> My long term goal is to be a well paid consultant and work remotely
> for limited hours ( lots of flexibility) If I accept this promotion of
> TL I might not be able to dedicate enough time to master my craft
> which I think is necessary for my long term goal.

It's good to keep your long term goals in mind. That said, most folks can find a way to master whatever is important enough to them.

> However hate to lose $ that comes with the promotion

Yes, there is always a money aspect.

Many companies offer a both technical career track and a management track. In my experience the most lucrative positions are in management, but that's certainly not always the case.

If your long range goal involves a remote, highly-paid, limited hours, non-management role, then it may be worthwhile to turn down a short-term raise.